# Python ctypes bool pointer

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I'm trying to pass a boolean pointer to a ctypes function, more specifically WINAPI's GetDevicePowerState function.

I've tried sending it in a lot of different ways, but i never get the value to change. I've tried wrapping the pointer in a byref/POINTER/pointer from the ctypes library. I've also tried not sending just a c_bool but also ctypes.wintypes.BOOL aswell as sending it as an integer, but it's value doesn't change either.

I've looked thru the docs but couldn't really see anything stand out regarding this, maybe i overlooked it?

Comment: setup: `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True);` `kernel32.GetDevicePowerState.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.BOOL))`

Comment: usage: `f = open(r'C:\Windows\notepad.exe');` `hDevice = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(f.fileno());` `is_working = wintypes.BOOL();` `success = kernel32.GetDevicePowerState(hDevice, ctypes.byref(is_working))`

Comment: @eryksun thanks, did the trick. looks like the GetDevicePowerState still isn't very good with monitors even on win 10 :( shame